# Using divs as tabs how can I change the background color on the one clicked and set the others back to original?

Tags: html, css, angular

```
<span class="row top-bar-left align-items-center" style="width: 80%; float:left">
        <div tabindex="1" class="link tab" routerLink="details" routerLinkActive="active"
            [queryParams]="activatedRoute.queryParams | async">
            <p>JDA-WMS Details</p>
        </div>
        <div tabindex="2" class="link tab" routerLink="summary" routerLinkActive="active"
            [queryParams]="activatedRoute.queryParams | async">
            <p>JDA-WMS Summary</p>
        </div>
        <div tabindex="3" class="link tab" routerLink="shortage" routerLinkActive="active"
            [queryParams]="activatedRoute.queryParams | async">
            <p>Shortage</p>
        </div>
    </span>
```

With ths code above I'm wanting to use the 3 DIVs as tabs. When I click one of them I want the background color to change. Then when I click another one I want it to change also and reset the original one back.

Comment: Just wondering if there's any reason for using `div` instead of `a`

Comment: [Please note that `div` is not a valid child of span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span), you should make the enclosing `span` a `div`. It won't fix your actual problem, but it will make your html valid

Answer (score 1):

You are already using `routerLinkActive` to give "active" css class to the active tab,
so all you need to do is some css tweaking

```
.tab.active {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 lines of jQuery like this:

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {
$('.tab').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.tab {
height:100px;width:100px;background:gray;margin:25px;cursor:pointer;
}

.tab.active {
background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="tab">1</div>
<div class="tab">2</div>
<div class="tab">3</div>
```

Comment: I haven't used JQuery before in an angular application. Can I do this? Sorry not very familiar with JQuery

Comment: I don't see why not, otherwise you can us vanilla JS equivalent.

Comment: @avia it is certainly possible but in general it is not a very angular way of handling things.

Comment: agreed. my experience with angular being limited I fellback on good ol' code :)